# ProFTPD - Failed to retrieve directory listing while using TLS

Tags: ssl, ftp, tls, proftpd, directory-listing

I have problem with my ProFTPD server.

When I try to connect to the server using TLS then I get timeout after MLSD command.
It only happens whenI use TLS - without it it works perfectly.

I checked these logs:

> proftpd.log - USER xxx: Login successful.
>
> tls.log - TLSv1/SSLv3 connection accepted ... Protection set to Private

Where could be problem please?
I can provide more informations, just ask for them in comments.

EDIT:
Today I tried to set INPUT policy of iptables to ALLOW ... everything worked ... so issue is a firewall. How should I set iptables to work with FTPS ?

Here are my iptables settings:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [930:61159]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [256:26448]
-A INPUT ! -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK ACK -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,20,21,25,143,993,110,995,1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: are you doing a directory listing as encrypted or non encrypted?

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure ... I don't use CLI client but FileZilla (I also tried Total Commander - it throws error that PORT command failed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that conntrack_ftp module, which on the fly allows ftp data connections to pass through firewall even if they were to be dropped because of rules, cannot analyze the encrypted stream for `PASV`/`PORT` commands. The same applies to not being able to use active mode from behind a firewall/nat with encrypted control connection.

So you need to set static ports for passive mode (or if client is not behind firewall/nat use an active mode) and add a firewall rule to accept incoming connections on these ports.

Ports for passive mode are set through [PassivePorts](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_PassivePorts.html) directive.

Edit: I should add that the amount of PassivePorts does not just limit the amount of parallel connections, but also limits a number of connections (read directory listings and/or file transfers) per `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait` seconds.
So if you are transfering a lot of small files, open up a lot of ports!

Comment: lol, so simple ... I though I have opened all those ports so I didn't even checked that. So I opened ports 50000:50500 (PassivePorts) and everythink seems ok. Thank you.

Comment: ofc, I just didn't have time to make more tests if it is really solved yet