# ProFTPd timeout on LIST

Tags: centos7, proftpd, ftps

Recently I've migrated a centOS 5 server to 7. But since then connection to FTP through FileZilla doesn't work unless I put FileZilla on FTP Plain Connection.

TLS doesn't work when getting the folder list
Logging in works fine. But it times-out after that.

```
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Status: Resolving address of something.com
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:21...
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5b Server ready.
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 234 AUTH TLS successful
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Status: Initializing TLS...
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Status: Verifying certificate...
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Status: TLS connection established.
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: USER xxxxx
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 331 Password required for xxxxx
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: PASS ***********
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 230 User xxxxx logged in
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 200 UTF8 set to on
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: PBSZ 0
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 200 PBSZ 0 successful
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: PROT P
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 200 Protection set to Private
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Status: Logged in
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: PWD
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: TYPE I
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 200 Type set to I
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: PASV
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,137,183).
2016-04-10 11:29:59 3348 1 Command: LIST
2016-04-10 11:30:19 3348 1 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
2016-04-10 11:30:19 3348 1 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
2016-04-10 11:31:41 3348 1 Status: Disconnected from server
```

The only thing I've managed to find so far is adding this to the proftpd.conf

```
  <IfModule mod_facts.c>
    FactsAdvertise off
  </IfModule>
```

This changes the command to LIST instead of MLSD. Yet it still times out for no reason. Does anyone have any idea?

EDIT: without TLS the connection works fine

```
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Status: Resolving address of something.com
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:21...
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5b Server ready.
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Command: USER xxxxx
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 331 Password required for xxxxx
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Command: PASS ***********
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 230 User xxxxxlogged in
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Command: SYST
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Command: FEAT
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 211-Features:
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  LANG en-US*
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  EPRT
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  EPSV
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  MDTM
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  SSCN
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  SIZE
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  PROT
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  CCC
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  PBSZ
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  AUTH TLS
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  REST STREAM
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response:  UTF8
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 211 End
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 200 UTF8 set to on
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Status: Logged in
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Command: PWD
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Command: TYPE I
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Response: 200 Type set to I
2016-04-10 11:21:28 8704 1 Command: PASV
2016-04-10 11:21:29 8704 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,139,173).
2016-04-10 11:21:29 8704 1 Command: LIST
2016-04-10 11:21:29 8704 1 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list
2016-04-10 11:21:29 8704 1 Response: 226 Transfer complete
2016-04-10 11:21:29 8704 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

Comment: Please provide a similar log when using non-ssl connection.

Comment: @tim Added to the main

Comment: In your original listing commands and responses are listed. This is what Im interested in. Can you raise debug level and show them please?

Comment: Any idea how I do that in Filezilla? When I switch to Plain FTP it just doesn't show the commands

Comment: No idea, I put my best guess based on your info in an answer.

Comment: Got it adding in now

Comment: Please add the same log for TLS version (with timestamps and all that).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38201/discussion-between-tim-and-s-lenders).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

[ProFTPD - Failed to retrieve directory listing while using TLS](https://serverfault.com/questions/352419/proftpd-failed-to-retrieve-directory-listing-while-using-tls?rq=1)

it might be a problem with the related rules of a firewall between you and the server.

Comment: +1, as got same problem with another ftp product and it was a firewall problem

Comment: Fixed it for me to after opening the ports in the firewall of the hosting company. Thanks tim